# Show that $g(z)=z_0+e^{i\theta}z$, $\theta = Arg(z_1-z_0)$, maps the real axis onto the line L through $z_0$ and $z_1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't understand the solution to this problem given in the textbook: "Note that g is a linear function of z with $g(0)=z_0$ and $g(|z_1-z_0|)=z_1$". Wouldn't this mean that g maps the line through $0$ and $|z_1-z_0|$ onto to L? Could someone please explain further what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book identifies the two special points on the real axis, i.e. $z=0$ and $z=|z_1-z_0|$ to show that the map passes through $z_0$ and $z_1$, respectively. It also argues that it is a linear map, translating the real axis into a line in the complex plane, which is true albeit less obvious.

---

Alternative, below is a more explicit proof. Let $z=a \in R$ be the real axis and $z_0=u_0+iv_0$, $z_1=u_1+iv_1$. Then,

$$g(z) = u+iv = u_0+iv_0 + ae^{i\theta}$$

Equate the real and imaginary parts,

$$u = u_0 + a\cos\theta, \>\>\>\>\>v= v_0+a\sin\theta$$

Eliminate $a$ to obtain

$$v-v_0 = \tan\theta (u-u_0)\tag 1$$

Since $\theta = Arg(z_1-z_0)$, we have $\tan\theta = \frac {v_1-v_0}{u_1-u_0}$ and the line equation (1) becomes

$$\frac{v-v_0}{u-u_0}=\frac{v_1-v_0}{u_1-u_0}$$

which represents a line going through both $z_0$ and $z_1$.